# Cakephp Standard - Is it the Proper standard to write things in controller

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

Sorry for this basic question. The following are the codes presented in my Userscontroller.php

```
public function register()
{
  //Setting some data
  $this->User->create();
  $this->User->save($this->request->data)
} 

public function edit()
{
  //Setting some data
  $this->User->save($this->request->data)
} 

public function admin_add()
{
  //Setting some data
  $this->User->create();
  $this->User->save($this->request->data)
} 

public function admin_edit()
{
  //Setting some data
  $this->User->save($this->request->data)
}
```

One of my senior reviewed this code and said that the above code not met the CAKEPHP Standard..Business logic need to move to model

like as follows in model

```
<?php 
class User extends AppModel {
  //Validation parts

     public functions savingData($data =array(), $id=false)
    {
       if($id == false)
       {
         $this->create();
       }
       $this->User->save($data)
    }
}?>
```

And in controllers he is asking to call this **savingData** function for Create and update options

Comment: Read about idea: Fat models and skinny controllers

Comment: I agree on fat models and skinny controllers, but I don't agree on this function, it seems practically useless to me.

Comment: Hey @Скачот your are telling about top code or bottom code ?

Comment: I think what you have in your controller actions is fairly correct, what you are doing in second code segment is wrapping save function and as Скач said it's practically useless.

Comment: Yep, that's my point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in MVC, business rules goes to model.

but in your example there is no any business logic so your code is correct to be in controller.

I suggest to use cakephp console to create controller and model and you can get it by yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Usually any method which has validations or save data to other tables or any extra functionality that makes the actions bigger than one page you need to consider it (break the function to smaller functions) and you can put this function base on your need and access into a Model or Component. I can say fat model concept and Component is used for this kind of situation.

I believe that methods shouldn't be more than one page this make the application maintainable for the next developer.

Also any static methods can be inside Utility as a class which can be called from controllers or views ... easily.

Bear in mind that Cake has lots of model behaviours which contained in all models. like beforeSave(), afterSave(), initiate(), before and after delete() ,...

At the end it is entirely up to you how you implement OOP, tidy and maintainable application.

> Other example imagine a Car.
>
> All the engine and complected stuff is inside box where you can't see it you can call it **Model** .
>   Controller stuff is in front of your hand so you can Controller it. **Controller**

Hope it helps if any one can add more option to this answer for others to learn.

Comment: Do you have any example for Faty model with Skiny controllers

Comment: Fat models and skinny controllers is more like a concept than a practical example. Every functionality that can be put in a model, should be there. Do as much logic as possible inside your model to keep your controller clean and easily readable. The controller should only use your tools defined in the model. Of course, it's not a strict rule, so when you feel a solution is better within a controller, go for it.

Comment: It's more like that any data manipulation that you will do, it should be done inside the model. For example, the classic "find top 5 recent posts" can be done as a wrapper function in the model to lighten the controller a bit.

Comment: Found this http://blog.andolasoft.com/2013/06/why-implement-fat-model-and-skinny-controller-in-cakephp.html

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking your boss is correct in that the goal is fat models - skinny controllers. The reason for this is that if at your work they are doing Unit testing ( which I hope they are ) this makes things MUCH easier on you.  Testing in the controller is a pain in the rear.

With that being said though the code in your controller is negligible so don't know if what he is asking is "neccessary" exactly, just technically not consistent with current standards ( which will change with time anyway ). Bottom line if you are bothered that he/she made this criticism, try not to be.  Things like this are not written in stone and are left up to interpretation for the most part.